# isotonic/increasing smooth function regression

Tags: r, smoothing, loess

I would like to fit a strictly increasing smooth function. Data can be generated as below

```
set.seed(100)
x  <- sort( runif(100) )
y  <- sort( runif(100)^2 )
y[sample.int(100,10)]  <- runif(10)
plot(x, y)
loessMod  <- loess("y~x", data=data.frame(x,y), span=3)
lines(x, predict(loessMod, x), col="red")
min( diff(loessMod$fitted) )
```

only way I found is playing with span in loess. Ex span=2 or 3 works, but 0.5 gives negative derivative. It would have been better if there was a way to enforce the positive derivative constraint though